# Wordpress Posts in Lightbox, how do I make google index these and not the single.post page

Tags: wordpress, lightbox, thickbox

This is my travel blog http://www.laaventura.co.uk

There is only a homepage with all post opening in a iframed thickbox lightbox

The thickbox class and extra link text is added with this javascript call after the page is loaded

```
a(".more-link").addClass("thickbox");
    a(".more-link").attr("href", function() {
        return this.href + "?KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=750px&width=500"
})
```

This adds the lightbox link to all read more links.

What I assume is that google will indexed the single-post.php file rather than opening the post in the lightbox on the home page is there any way to make google link directly to the lightbox?

Answer (score 0):

You are exactly right...  bots will not index content within the iframe, but WILL index the single posts.  Not a good scenario.   ;-)